# How can I center a window in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, window

How can I center a window in Windows 7?

Answer (score 4):

Sizer will do that for you: http://www.brianapps.net/sizer.html

**EDIT:** Here are some instructions:

1. Install and Run.
2. Sizer adds an icon to the Notification Area / System Tray. Double-Click it.
3. The Sizer Configuration window appears.
4. Click the Add button.
5. Another 640x480 item is added to the bottom of the list. Click on it.
6. Change the Description to "Center". Select "Don't resize window" and Move to: "Center".
7. Click OK.
8. Open an Explorer window. Right-Click its Maximize button. Click Center.

Comment: Seems to note that Vista isn't supported. That doesn't give me any hope that it would on 7.

Comment: It works on Windows 7.

Comment: Runs but doing nothing

Comment: I've added some instructions. Let me know how you get on with them.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to natively put the window in the exact center of the screen. Do you need it in the exact center? You could always just eyeball it--it shouldn't make that much of a difference, should it?

You could also drag the window to the top of the screen to maximize it, but I don't know if that's what you want.

Comment: Makes me think of using a level to make sure a picture on the wall is straight. If it *looks* straight, then it doesn't matter if it really is or not. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the question, but do you mean when you drag the window to the top and it snaps or when you open the window you want it to stay centered?